# Proper notation for subsets associated to the elements of another set.

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Say I have a set of buildings $B$ with a single building $b \in B$ and a set of people $P$ with single persons $p \in P$.

What would be the proper notation for a subset of people in $P$, that live in a building $p$ which comprehensibly associates this subset to the respective building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could write many different notations, depending on your emphasis/context. I would consider something like "For each $b\in B $, define $P_b $ to be the set of people who live in building $b $.".

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed. Just wasn't sure if there is a common convention on how to denote these subsets.

Answer (score 1):

You could define a function $f \colon P \to B$ that maps every person to the building he or she lives in. Then, $f^{-1} (b)$ would be the set of people that live in building $b$.

Comment: I think you mean $f^{-1}\left(\{b\}\right)$. Without the set braces, what you wrote doesn't traditionally make sense if any building has two or more people in it.

Comment: That would be the correct notation, but the sloppy version I wrote is also quite common.